# Convert Listener to Single in RxJava2

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I am using the Play Services [Auth api Phone](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/phone/package-summary) and so far I have the foll

```
  fun startSmsListener() {
    val client = SmsRetriever.getClient(applicationContext /* context */);
    val task = client.startSmsRetriever();
    task.addOnSuccessListener(object : OnSuccessListener<Void> {
        override fun onSuccess(p0: Void?) {
             //do somethin
        }

    })
    task.addOnFailureListener(object : OnFailureListener {
        override fun onFailure(p0: Exception) {
            //Handle error
        }

    })
}
```

Now I want to put this in an SmsManager class and convert it into an Single/Observable so I can handle it in a reactive way in my viewmodel. How can I do that?

So far I've got this:

```
var single = Single.create(SingleOnSubscribe<Void> { e ->
                val task = client.startSmsRetriever()
                task.addOnSuccessListener {
                    e.onSuccess(it)
                }
                task.addOnFailureListener {
                    e.onError(it)
                }
        })
```

But I am unsure as to whether this code is correct or not, whether there is something im missing like removing the listeners after disposal.

Any help?

Comment: `Single<Void>` doesn't work as `null`s are not allowed. Use `Completable`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are interested in a "boolean" value - either connected or not connected, thus instead of `Single` you should use `Completable`:

```
Completable.create { emitter -> 
    val client = SmsRetriever.getClient(applicationContext)
    val task = client.startSmsRetriever() 
    task.addOnSuccessListener { emitter.onComplete() } 
    task.addOnFailureListener { emitter.tryOnError(it) }
}
```

Comment: You don't really need `!it.isDisposed` here. `it.onComplete`/`it.tryOnError` will do it for you.

Comment: can you expand on that @akarnokd

Answer (score 1):

While creating a `Completable` manually will work, you might also have a look at the [RxTask](https://github.com/niqo01/RxTask/) project. It provides "RxJava 2 binding for Google Play Services Task APIs".

If you need it just in one place, an extra library would certainly be an overkill. But if you plan to use more Play Services together with RxJava, it might be worth a look...

It doesn't (yet) provide a wrapper explicitly for `SmsRetriever`, but the general task helper classes would probably be enough:

```
val client = SmsRetriever.getClient(applicationContext)
val smsReceiver = CompletableTask.create(client::startSmsRetriever)
```